# Why can't I end an active socket in node.js without causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: node.js, sockets, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to stop some http servers in node.js but I don't want to wait for all `keep-alive` connections to timeout before the servers can fully close. So, I've been trying to keep track of all active sockets and then when the server needs to be stopped I want to call `.end()` on them to let the client know that I want to close the socket. However, when I do this I get a segmentation fault.

I have used a segmentation-fault handler to get a better stack trace but I can't figure out what could be going wrong.

Here is the code to keep track of the connections:

```
connectionNum = 1
activeHttpConnections = {}

trackConnection = (map, socket) ->
    # save active socket
    id = connectionNum
    map[id.toString()] = socket

    # remove socket once it closes
    socket.on 'close', ->
        map[id.toString()] = null
        delete map[id.toString()]

    # reset connection number eventually
    if connectionNum > 1000000
        connectionNum = 1
    else
        connectionNum++
```

When the server is started I call:

```
httpServer.on 'connection', (socket) -> trackConnection activeHttpConnections, socket
```

And when I stop the servers I call:

```
# close active connection so that servers can stop
for key, socket of activeHttpConnections
    socket.end()
```

When `.end()` is called I get the following stacktrace:

```
PID 29943 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x58
/home/ryan/git/openhim-core-js/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x1185)[0x7f50a037e185]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7f50a2384340]
node(_ZN4node10StreamWrap8ShutdownERKN2v820FunctionCallbackInfoINS1_5ValueEEE+0x166)[0x9d1846]
node(_ZN2v88internal25FunctionCallbackArguments4CallEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEE+0x9b)[0x616d9b]
node[0x6356b6]
[0x270b80a060a2]
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong, or what this stacktrace could point to?

Comment: What node version are you using? Also you might be better off using a [uuid](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-uuid) for a socket ID since currently your code will overwrite sockets if `connectionNum` reaches its limit in a short period of time.

Comment: I'm running 0.11.13 as I need generator support. I agree uuids may be better but I don't expect to get to a million active connections.

Comment: I've created a node issue because it should never seg fault even if my code is wrong: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8597

Comment: Ah an unstable node version, so that's not entirely unexpected. On a semi-related note, if you're feeling adventurous, you can [get a list of connected sockets (for a specific server) via an undocumented method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26511320/2050455) (so you don't have to keep a separate object around).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'l take a look. In other news, I've been able to reproduce this separately from my application and have updated the node issue. Hopefully someone from Joyent will help get to the bottom of this soon.